# Trying to prevent deletion of a Note with a before delete trigger. Below code is not working

Tags: before-trigger, delete, notes, contentnote

Please find the below code:

```
trigger DeleteNote on Note (before delete) {

    for(Note N : trigger.old){

        if(Trigger.isDelete){

            N.adderror('Note Cannot be deleted');
        }

    }

}
```

Please suggest changes for this trigger to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update :**

If you are using `Enhanced Notes`, then you will have to write a trigger on [`ContentDocument`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) object. When using `Enhanced Notes`, it does not create `Notes` rather it creates [`ContentNote`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) records. You can find the [structure](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm#!) of the `ContentNote` which is much more complex, so you will have to change your trigger to be on `ContentDocument` and not on `Note`

And this is how your trigger should look like

```
trigger DeleteNote on ContentDocument (before delete) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete){
        Map<Id, ContentDocument> mapContentDocument = new Map<Id, ContentDocument>([Select Id, FileExtension from ContentDocument where Id in: trigger.oldMap.keyset()]);
        for(ContentDocument cd : Trigger.Old){
            if(mapContentDocument.containsKey(cd.Id) && mapContentDocument.get(cd.Id).FileExtension == 'snote' ){
                cd.adderror('Note Cannot be deleted');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Your trigger should be on `before delete` event and not on `after delete`. In `after delete` event, the `note` would already have be deleted. So just change the event and your trigger should work fine.

```
trigger DeleteNote on Note (before delete) {
    if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore){
        for(Note N : trigger.old){
            N.adderror('Note Cannot be deleted');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .It is still not working. Case owner is able to delete the Note.

Comment: @Sneha Did you change the event from `after delete` to `before delete` ?

Comment: Yes...I've tried the same trigger you've mentioned in the comment

Comment: Thank you!. trigger on ContentDocument worked

Answer (score 0):

If your trigger on Note is not firing for the note you are deleting then it is the enhanced note you are deleting not the old note.

I this case you should write trigger on **ContentDocument** object and check them with matching id in trigger.old.

```
trigger DeleteContentDocument on ContentDocument (before delete) {
    for(ContentDocument cd: [SELECT Id, FileExtension FROM ContentDocument WHERE FileExtension = 'snote' and Id =: trigger.oldMap.keyset() ]){
        trigger.oldMap.get(cd.Id).adderror('Note Cannot be deleted');                         
    }
}
```

> Note:- You cannot write trigger on ContentNote. Also, I have not
>   choosen the contentdocumentLink because one note can be shared with
>   multiple records and hence the multiple contentDocumentLink will be
>   generated. You need to write extra stuff to handle them.

Comment: Errors can only be added on the `context variables`, you have queried the record and  trying to add error to that record not to the one which is in transaction. This will give you `System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors`

Comment: Ahh, Thanks for highlighting it. corrected it now.